# How do I tell how much time is left on Felix Felicis?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

The game says it lasts for "one in game day (48 min)". But after using it, nothing changes in my UI.

**Is there a way to tell how much time I have left** before I need to use another one?  Failing that, **is there a way to even see if it's still active?**

Comment: I think that in every video I saw, the potion icon on the tool-wheel  would turn gray on use, and gradually regain color as the effects expires. Mostly noticeable on focus potions that can be extended by casting spells