# Does advancing time expire potion effects?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

Some potions have a set duration, most noticeable the preorder exclusive Felix Felicis that is reported to lasts for a full in-game day (48 minutes).

[image]

[Since it is not simple to check the remaining time on a potion effect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/401643/how-do-i-tell-how-much-time-is-left-on-felix-felicis), I was wondering if advancing time in game reduce that timer?